# How to display banner in web channel chat bot developed using MS Bot framework in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, botframework, chatbot

I am trying to have a banner kind of thing(which we usually display it in websites) displayed in the Web Channel chat BOT which was developed using MS Bot Framework in C#.

The idea i want to implement is:

The banner  will be kind of in frozen in position where is it is placed even though the bot conversation is going long and it should will be visible at the top with a hyperlink related to Login which when clicked should redirect user to the Login Dialog in the BOT for to login and continue to work.

During the launch of the BOT the actual conversation would in form of QnA but any time the user wants to go to access other features of BOT he has to login so instead of showing during answering every time the long prompt when a particular query is answered, what we thought of is have banner kind of thing displayed at the top as we have in websites and during which when the conversation starts it would be from QnA since the banner is visible at top for every user every time with login link he can click on the link to go access advanced features developed in BOT.

Hope the idea i am trying to explain is understood. Coming to the query:

I am not sure how to achieve it as i don't have a clue where to even start and don't know weather this is possible or achievable or is it a meaningful expectation?

Is it possible to pull this out through some JavaScript?

Any insight on achieving this would be very helpful.

Thanks in Advance

ChaitayaNG

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) which allows your bot to be embedded (with customizations) onto a web page. In this way you can build in many different types of functionality, including the ability to pass events/activities between the bot and the page.

From the [samples list](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#samples-list), you should look over the #15 and #16 sample groups. These demonstrate how you can design a page to send or receive data to/from your bot, whether that comes from a button click or uploading data or simply navigating to the page. While I don't fully understand your end goal, I do understand that you are wanting functionality on the page that will allow the user to interact with the bot. These should get you well on your way, in that regard.

Hope of help!